# What does two asterisks (**) mean in this strange USA phone number?

Tags: usa

[image]

This is a screenshot from an [11foot8](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXX0RWOIBjt4o3ziHu-6a5A) video. Notice the phone number on the All My Sons truck: **MOVE.

I know that you can dial in the letters as numbers if you check the letters on your keypad, but I've never seen those two asterisks before. What do they represent? I haven't found anything on [All My Sons' website](https://allmysons.com) (looks like their number has changed).

Comment: Not really a travel question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a travel question.

Comment: Certainly doesn't immediately strike me as a phone number.... so they've had to prefix it with "call" to show that.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

These are special **"StarStar" numbers** offered by StarStar Mobile: https://www.starstarmobile.com/

So the asterisks don't really represent anything, they're literal representations of `*` key/button you find on any phone.

While I'm not familiar with the details of the implementation, it appears to be a clever hack on VSCs, which are how telcos let you control various telephony features via the network itself:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_service_code

So presumably the Star Star folks have struck a deal with the big telcos to route any calls starting with `**` their way, and they can then forward the calls to the paying customers.

Comment: Specifically, it seems to be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_dial_code